# How do I format follow up paragraph(s) with hanging indention so the header numbering has no text under it within that heading?

Tags: indentation

I am using Latex to write a document that needs specific formatting, as follows:

[image]

I am using `documentclass`: `article`, and `pagestyle`: `fancy` (from fancyhd package},  and had it working almost perfectly by using the following for section, subsection.  The paragraph part never worked, so I ended up using an ordered list, which had the problem of not having hanging indention for the sub-sub-paragraphs.

```
\newcommand{\subSubSectionStart}{\begin{enumerate}[label(\arabic*),leftmargin=2.5\parindent]}
\newcommand{\subSubSection}[1]{\item #1}
\newcommand{\subSubSectionEnd}{\end{enumerate}}
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}[]

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont}{\theparagraph}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{\parindent}{1em}{1ex}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
```

However, after writing a good bit of the document this way with everything looking pretty good, i realized I made a fundamental error by misusing section headings.  My in-line code looked like this:

```
\section{SECTION TITLE}
\subsection{\myBoldUnderLineMacro{SUBSECTION TITLE:} blah blah blah blah .... an entire paragraph, often quite long went here, often with many macros to generate dynamic content.}
% BELOW PARAGRAPH SECTION NEVER WORKED QUITE RIGHT
\paragraph{\myBoldUnderLineMacro{SUBSUBSECTION TITLE:} blah blah blah blah .... an entire paragraph, often quite long went here, often with many macros to generate dynamic content.}
% BELOW WORKED, EXCEPT NO HANGING INDENT, AND NOT GREAT WHEN THERE
% IS A LONG BIT OF TEXT IN IT, WOULD PREFER AN INLINE SOLUTION
% IF POSSIBLE
\subSubSectionStart
    \subSubSection{Text goes here, text goes here, text goes here...}
    \subSubSection{Text goes here, text goes here, text goes here...}
\subSubSectionEnd
```

This looked great until I started to get longer subsections and sections with many subsections at which point LaTeX's attempt to keep heading names together appears to have started to cause page overruns.

Now that I know that I need to change the use of the headers to this:

```
\section{SECTION TITLE}
\subsection{\SUBSECTION TITLE:}
blah blah blah blah .... an entire paragraph, often quite long went here, often with many macros to generate dynamic content.
% BELOW NEVER WORKED CORRECTLY, BUT WOULD PREFER
% TO FIX PARAGRAPH THAN USE MY HOME-MADE COMMAND IF POSSIBLE.
\paragraph{SUBSUBSECTION TITLE:} % OR SUBSUBSECTION IF AVAILABLE
blah blah blah blah .... an entire paragraph, often quite long went here, often with many macros to generate dynamic content.
```

I am struggling to figure out how to get the formatting back to what I want it.  By going through and separating the section/subsection names again I've fixed the page overruns (that took forever to figure out!), but now I need to figure out how to get the formatting back to what was indicated above.

My starting point in trying to fix it is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont}{\thesubsection.}{.5em}{}[]

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont}{\theparagraph}{.5em}{}[]
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{\parindent}{1em}{1ex}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
```

This successfully removed line breaks after subsections, but I'm at a loss as to how to get the hanging indents to work, and how to modify follow up text between sections/subsections (if possible... nice to have only since there aren't many items in the document that are not ordered).

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that we can just copy and paste without having to replicate the complete document structure first?

Comment: Absolutely, but are you more interested in me reproducing the one that did not work because of overflow, or what I have now that doesn't give the correct document formatting at all?

Comment: Whatever the current state of your work is!